# VS 2015, C# 6 and MSBuild 12.0

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

I use Visual Studio 2015 and target platform of all projects in solution is .Net Framework 4.5.1
But I can use all c# 6 features in the Code like null conditional operator and so on.
How it works?
Will I have problem on build server with MSBuild 12.0 ?

Comment: You need to install the new build tools on the build server.

Comment: I'm curious, didn't you try to google for this? Both questions have been asked, answered and closed as duplicate many times already